# How to getText from next input whilst in a loop

Tags: java

please look at the code below.
I am creating a program to manually input the marks of 5 subjects, find the average marks, total marks, and the final grade. This will be done for 10 students.

I am required to only use one textbox to input the marks and one to input the students' names. I am getting an error since the program thinks that there is a blank space (" ") while the marks are being input after the first iteration. Is there any way to make the 'inputmarks' blank so that the next subject marks can be input?

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
// initialization
float total_mark = 0;
float average = 0;

// actual working
for (int count = 0; count <= 10; count++)
    // count <= 10 as there are 10 students
{
    
    // input marks for 5 subjects for each student
  String name = (nametxt.getText());
  
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    float mark = Integer.parseInt(inputmarks.getText());
    total_mark = total_mark + mark;
    inputmarks.setText("");
    subjlbl.setText("Enter marks for Subject "+(i+1)+":");
}    
    
    average = total_mark / 5;
    
    outputarea.append("Name of Student: "+name+"\n");
    outputarea.append("Marks of Student: "+total_mark+"\n");
    outputarea.append("Avg marks: "+average+"\n");
    
    
    //looking for grade
    
    if (average >= 90) 
        outputarea.append("Grade: A"+"\n");    
    else if (average >= 80) 
        outputarea.append("Grade: B"+"\n"); 
    else if (average >= 70) 
        outputarea.append("Grade: C"+"\n");    
    else if (average >= 60) 
        outputarea.append("Grade: D"+"\n");    
    else if (average >= 50) 
        outputarea.append("Grade: E"+"\n");    
    else outputarea.append("Grade :F"+"\n");

 
        nametxt.setText("");
```

Comment: I'm trying to read the code, but where `nametxt` comes from? Did you cut the code? We need more information

Comment: @ermp hi, nametxt is just the textbox used to input the student's name. At the end of the code, i used nametxt.setText(" ") so that the textbox will be blank and the next student name can be input. Thanks

Comment: Original poster: please format your code better, and consider posting a valid [mre]  program with your question.

Comment: you cannot input one by one as per your logic...for loop does not wait for you to put the next input. programming languages can fit into our reality but not your imagination.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After get marks you should get only texts from inputmarksEditText and nametxt without get any space from text _if there is any space in text _ , You should use `trim`

Change these codes

```
float mark = Integer.parseInt(inputmarks.getText());

  // input marks for 5 subjects for each student
  String name = (nametxt.getText().toString().trim);
```

Into

```
float mark = Integer.parseInt(inputmarks.getText().toString().trim);

String student_name = nametxt.getText().trim;
```

After that to make text empty after get text from it , you should use

```
nametxt.setText("");
inputmarks.setText("");
subjlbl.setTextHint("Enter marks for Subject "+(i+1)+":");
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I'm not sure if this can be applied here, but I hope this may help in some way.

I would try to make an array out of your name variable like:

```
String[] name = (nametxt.getText().split(" ");
```

Then you can make an integer array from your name array by parsing it like:

```
int[] numCoordinates = {Integer.parseInt(name[0]), Integer.parseInt(name[1])....};
```